# Use a field value as a time units in an interval expression

Tags: sql, vertica

I have to following tables:

```
dim_table:

Name   | time_unit
--------------------
Mark   | 5
Kim    | 10
```

and

```
main_table:

Name   | Time
-------------------------------
Mark   | 10-10-2020 08:00:00
Mark   | 10-10-2020 08:00:01
Mark   | 10-10-2020 08:00:02
Mark   | 10-10-2020 08:00:03
Mark   | 10-10-2020 08:00:04
Mark   | 10-10-2020 08:00:05
Mark   | 10-10-2020 08:00:06
Mark   | 10-10-2020 08:00:07
Mark   | 10-10-2020 08:00:08
Mark   | 10-10-2020 08:00:09
Mark   | 10-10-2020 08:00:10
```

I want to use the following SQL expression as a part of my SQL query:

```
main_table.Time RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '5' second PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

How can I use the `time_unit` value of Mark from `dim_table` instead of `'5' second`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff's expression would work - and so would `TIMESTAMPADD(ss,time_unit,<your_starting_value>)` - But what would _your_starting_value_ be? Or do you want different gaps in the `TIMESERIES` clause, depending on the value in the dim table?

Comment: actually I want it to be part of the following SQL:
`sum(some_value) OVER(PARTITION BY some_other_value ORDER BY time RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '5 second' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`.
when I use @GordonLinoff's expression I get the following error:
`window frame logical or physical offset must be a constant`.

Answer (score 1):

With this error:

error: window frame logical or physical offset must be a constant

that you pasted in one comment above, you actually have the answer: It won't work if you wish different `RANGE`s for different values of time unit in the dimension table. It expects a constant and not an expression.

The only workaround that comes to my mind is a UNION SELECT of otherwise identical queries, but with a constant `RANGE` expression that matches all different values in `time_unit`. The query below runs on any Vertica cluster, as it brings its own data with it: A `WITH` clause with 2 Common Table Expressions (CTE-s), followed by the real query.

```
WITH
-- your input ...
dim_table(nam,time_unit) AS (
          SELECT 'Mark', 5
UNION ALL SELECT 'Kim' ,10
)
,
main_table(nam,ts,qty) AS (
-- your input plus the same data for 'Kim' ...
          SELECT 'Mark', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:00',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:01',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:02',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:03',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:04',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:05',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:06',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:07',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:08',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:09',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Kim' , TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:00',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Kim' , TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:01',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Kim' , TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:02',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Kim' , TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:03',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Kim' , TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:04',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Kim' , TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:05',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Kim' , TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:06',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Kim' , TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:07',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Kim' , TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:08',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'Kim' , TIMESTAMP '2020-10-10 08:00:09',10
)
-- real query starts here:
SELECT
  dim_table.nam
, SUM(qty) OVER (w RANGE BETWEEN '5 SECONDS' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rngsum
, COUNT(*) OVER (w RANGE BETWEEN '5 SECONDS' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS ctrl
FROM dim_table
JOIN main_table USING(nam)
WHERE time_unit=5
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY dim_table.nam ORDER BY ts)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  dim_table.nam
, SUM(qty) OVER (w RANGE BETWEEN '10 SECONDS' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rngsum
, COUNT(*) OVER (w RANGE BETWEEN '10 SECONDS' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS ctrl
FROM dim_table
JOIN main_table USING(nam)
WHERE time_unit=10
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY dim_table.nam ORDER BY ts)
;
-- out  nam  | rngsum | ctrl 
-- out ------+--------+------
-- out  Mark |     10 |    1
-- out  Mark |     20 |    2
-- out  Mark |     30 |    3
-- out  Mark |     40 |    4
-- out  Mark |     50 |    5
-- out  Mark |     60 |    6
-- out  Mark |     60 |    6
-- out  Mark |     60 |    6
-- out  Mark |     60 |    6
-- out  Mark |     60 |    6
-- out  Kim  |     10 |    1
-- out  Kim  |     20 |    2
-- out  Kim  |     30 |    3
-- out  Kim  |     40 |    4
-- out  Kim  |     50 |    5
-- out  Kim  |     60 |    6
-- out  Kim  |     70 |    7
-- out  Kim  |     80 |    8
-- out  Kim  |     90 |    9
-- out  Kim  |    100 |   10
```